# How to write connection string to connect from classic ASP page to SQL 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I connect from classic ASP page to SQL SERVER 2008 R2 with following connection string

`"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=my_db;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=my_user;Password=my_pass;"`

but I get error

`Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

I verified that `my_db` exists!, so what is wrong in my connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(local)` name you've given for your data source is invalid. It should be an IP address, server name or server/instance name of your SQL installation.

**UPDATE**

If the SQL server is on the webserver you can use `.` to specify local. Here's an example connection string from one of my classic ASP projects:

`"Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=.;Database=my_db;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;"`

Comment: I run asp classic page on the same machine where SQL is installed. In ASP.NET I use (local) but in ASP Classic it doesn't work

Comment: In which case you can use `.` to specify a local SQL installation. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I tried it and now it says `Login failed for user 'user'`. I checked and user exist and mapped to 'my_db' database. what can be the problem now?

Comment: The connection string is now working in that case, the user credentials you supplied were incorrect. Have you checked them in the security settings of the database?

Comment: Fixed it. The reason was 'An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only'. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an oledb provider to prevent it trying to default to ODBC (and failing)

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=my_db;User ID=XXX;Password=YYY;
```

(You also need the 2008 SQL Client OleDb provider installed on the machine)

Comment: I tried it and now it says Login failed for user 'XXX'. I checked and user exist and mapped to 'my_db' database. what can be the problem now?

Comment: Are you using a named instance? Look in the server log to see why the login request was denied

Comment: Fixed it. The reason was 'An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only'. Thx. Sorry, but I can't accept 2 answer and because Rory answered first so I'll accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

try to change (local) with : 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=(local);Database=my_db;Uid=my_user; Pwd=my_pass;
```

If in doubt, check [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008#p2).